# How do I change the text-color of a button in HTML to a random color upon clicking it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I've tried the following code:

```html
<button id = "changeColor">Click here to change my color</button>
<script>
var changeButton = document.getElementById('changeColor');

function random(number){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*number);
}

function switchColor(){
    var randomColor = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
}
changeButton.addEventListener('click', switchColor);
</script>
```

but the button doesn't return any color upon clicking it.

Thanks a lot in advance for answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `color` in `style` of the selected button with the genrated random color.

```
changeButton.style.color = randomColor
```

```html
<button id = "changeColor">Click here to change my color</button>
<script>
var changeButton = document.getElementById('changeColor');

function random(number){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*number);
}

function switchColor(){
    var randomColor = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
    changeButton.style.color = randomColor
    console.log(randomColor);
}
changeButton.addEventListener('click', switchColor);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id = "changeColor">Click here to change my color</button>
<script>
    var changeButton = document.getElementById('changeColor');
    
    function random(number){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*number);
    }
    
    function switchColor(){
        var randomColor = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
        // CHANGE THE TEXT COLOR
        document.getElementById("changeColor").style.color = randomColor;
    }
    changeButton.addEventListener('click', switchColor);
    </script>
```

Comment: FYI: you already have access to `this` or `changeButton`. No need to query the DOM again with `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way

Your Code Is Missing

```
changeButton.style.color = color;
```

```js
var changeButton = document.getElementById('changeColor');

function random(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function switchColor(){
    var color;
    color = 'rgb(' + random(0, 255) + ',' + random(0, 255) + ',' + random(0, 255) + ')';
    changeButton.style.color = color;
}
changeButton.addEventListener('click', switchColor);
```

```css
button{ border: none; }
```

```html
<button id = "changeColor">Click here to change my color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it more precise, try this

```js
var changeButton = document.getElementById('changeColor');
changeButton.onclick= () => {
     var randomColor = 'rgb(' + Math.random()*255 + ',' + Math.random()*255 + ',' + Math.random()*255 + ')';
    changeButton.style.color = randomColor
}
```

```html
<button id = "changeColor">Click here to change my color</button>
```